# Knockout validation with HTML attributes

Tags: html, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Can I just add HTML attributes to my element to wireup validation?

If so, it doesn't seem to be working for me. Do I need to do something extra?

https://jsfiddle.net/FcM2A/1/

```
vm required<input data-bind="value: num1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/><br/>
HTML5 required<input required="true" data-bind="value: num2, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /><br/>
num1 isValid: <span data-bind="text: num1.isValid()"></span><br/>
num2 isValid: <span data-bind="text: num2.isValid()"></span>
<p data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($root)"></p>

ko.validation.init( {parseInputAttributes: true, writeInputAttributes: true} ); //enable HTML5 validation, write HTML5 validation attributes to the controls

var viewModel = {
    num1: ko.observable("1").extend({ required: true }),
    num2: ko.observable("2")
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: I was hoping it could be done in the markup. Is that not possible? This issue https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/issues/117 seems to imply that you can do it that way.

Comment: Are you expecting **num2.isValid()** to return true or fAlse.. Let me check

Comment: same as num1, false when blank, true when it's not

Answer (score 6):

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/FcM2A/29/

You are missing:

```
ko.validatedObservable(viewModel);
```

---

```
vm required<input data-bind="value: num1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/><br/>
HTML5 required<input required="true" data-bind="value: num2, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /><br/>
num1 isValid: <span data-bind="text: num1.isValid()"></span><br/>
num2 isValid: <span data-bind="text: num2.isValid()"></span>
<p data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($root)"></p>

ko.validation.init( {parseInputAttributes: true, writeInputAttributes: true} ); //enable HTML5 validation, write HTML5 validation attributes to the controls

var viewModel = {
    num1: ko.observable("1").extend({ required: true }),
    num2: ko.observable("2")
};
ko.validatedObservable(viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```